# Al ejecutar php artisan migrate me salta el siguiente error

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-8

Me salta este error ya verifique el nombre de mi BD en env. y esta todo bien, el puerto en donde se ejecuta el mysql es 3306, no se cual seria el problema.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'instituto' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = instituto and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\instituto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\instituto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'instituto'")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\instituto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=instituto", "root", "", [])
```

Comment: unknown database instituto, ¿está creada esta base de datos? si es así ¿está funcionando en el resto de llamadas a la bd?

Comment: Si esta creada, no se cual seria el problema, estoy empezando recién con la programación, también en el localhost rechaza la conexión, ahora recién estoy empezando con el proyecto

Comment: Para cuando el localhost te rechaza la conexión tienes habilitado el servicio de mysql? igualmente verifica las credenciales y nombre de la db en tu .env y ejecuta php artisan optimize para limpiar cache e intenta de nuevo

Comment: Los demás problemas ya pude solucionar, pero localhost me sigue sin funcionar, si esta habilitado el mysql